# Hangfire job gets requeued indefinitely (or stuck in processing status)

Tags: hangfire

I have a problem with an **hangfire job**. My job can take let's say 10 minutes to run and even though I have the `[AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0)]` attribute, the job seems to be **repeated indefinitely**.

If I check the result of the job it looks like the job is finished, but it seems like just a second before going into Succeeded state, it gets **re-queued**.

I think it is the invisible retry functionality coming to place because I can see that the job does not start immediately, but with a longer interval any time.

I use hangfire pro with redis database.

Comment: What Hangfire version are you using? Do you have logs? Sometimes this behavior is caused by the [Redis Client Timeout](http://redis.io/topics/clients#client-timeouts). Please ensure the client timeout value is 0.

Comment: It was exactly that. Can you write this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @odinserj if you add this as an answer it can help other people too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Redis as a job storage, this behavior may be caused by [Client Timeout](http://redis.io/topics/clients#client-timeouts) in Redis. By default, it is turned off, however some hosting environments have their own default value. Since workers expect the connection is still open after performing a background job, long-running jobs may cause an exception by writing to a closed socket.

You can turn off this setting via `redis.conf` or simply using the command:

```
CONFIG SET timeout 0
```